# IComparer interface is to Comparison delegate as IEqualityComparer is to what?

Tags: c#, .net

I like the [Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate, it's easier to make one than an IComparer.

Is there an analogous delegate for IEqualityComparer?

IComparer interface is to Comparison delegate as IEqualityComparer is to what?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't think of one in the BCL. Closest I can think of might be the [`Predicate<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate, but it's not really the same (only takes one object rather than comparing two). Beyond someone knowing one (which I wouldn't be surprised; I don't know the full BCL like the back of my hand _yet_), you might just end up having to rolling your own delegate signature. EDIT: Maybe `delegate bool EqualityComparison<T>(T left, T right)` (or maybe `Func<T, T, bool>`) but you'll have issues using it with the BCL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no equivalent because there can't be one. `IComparer<T>` defines only a single member, so you can "distill" it into a delegate.

In contrast, `IEqualityComparer<T>` must provide both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations in order to be universally useful. You can't fit both of these into a delegate, hence no equivalent to `Comparison<T>`.

That said, the signature of a delegate that directly compares two instances of a type `T` for equality would be the one given for [`EqualityComparer<T>.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132128.aspx) -- i.e. `Func<T, T, bool>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement your generic EqualityComparer:

```
 public class GenericEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
 {
     private Func<T, T, bool> equalsFunction;
     private Func<T, int> getHashCodeFunction;

     public GenericEqualityComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equalsFunction, Func<T, int> getHashCodeFunction)
     {
         this.equalsFunction = equalsFunction;
         this.getHashCodeFunction = getHashCodeFunction;
     }

     public bool Equals(T x, T y)
     {
         return this.equalsFunction(x, y);
     }

     public int GetHashCode(T obj)
     {
         return this.getHashCodeFunction(obj);
     }
 }
```

and use it like:

```
var list = new[]{"A","B","C","A"};
var distinct = list.Distinct(
      new GenericEqualityComparer<string>(
             (a,b) => a.Equals(b), 
             a => a.GetHashCode()));
```